# Force cell to "clear" contents in bootstrap thumbnail table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have generated a table that is displayed within a "container" and "thumbnail" div in the twitter bootstrap framework. One of the cells contains buttons that I would like to be displayed on a single line, so there are within a `<nobr>` tag. The issue is that the "button" images extend beyond the limits of the table. Is there an easy fix?

Demo here: http://www.bootply.com/ElSeqdESoO#

The fix should use dynamic column widths (other columns should wrap there contents, preventing the final column from extending beyond the table boundary).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the last column not having enough width. Providing, you wouldn't mind to have equal width of the columns (any number), add this to css.

```
table{ table-layout: fixed; }
```

Best regards

Comment: Apologies - I'll clarify the question, I need to stick with dynamic column widths

Comment: Don't get confused with the term 'fixed'. I'm pretty sure it'll keep dynamic column widths such as responsiveness. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not necessarily compatible with all browsers, using CSS flexible boxes. I added the following attribute to the `<nobr>` tag:

`style="display:flex; flex-shrink: 0; min-width:60px;"`

This causes the icons to be wrapped in a flexbox which is also prevented from shrinking beyond 60px.